# set variable for use in next task

Tags: ansible

I have imported the instance list, and I have used ec2_instance_fact together facts of the instance.

Now I need to get details of instance type , private IP and all for instances so that I can delete this and create new once with data with encryption

below is code it half one.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
  - instaceId.yaml
  tasks:

    - name: print module name one by one
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ Instance }}"

    - name: get metadata of Instance
      ec2_instance_facts:
        instance_ids: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ Instance }}"
      register: ec2_metadata

    - name: Record Users Access Keys
      debug: var= "{{ ec2_metadata.results[{{ item }}].instances[0].instance_id }}"
      with_sequence: start=0 end={{ec2_metadata.results|length -1}}

    - ec2:
        region: "{{ ec2_metadata.results[{{ item }}].instances[0].placement.availability_zone }}"
        state: absent
        instance_id: "{{ ec2_metadata.results[{{ item }}].instances[0].instance_id }}"
        with_sequence: start=0 end={{ ec2_metadata.results|length -1 }}
```

ideally I was assuming it should take

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "ec2_metadata.results[0].instances[0].instance_id": "i-03dbfd81f19297092"
```

only i-03dbfd81f19297092

could anyone suggest I can proceed

I got below error

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: \"{{ ec2_metadata.results[{{ item }}].instances[0].instance_id }}\""}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use loop module of ansible to iterate over desired attributes

```
- name: Record Users Access Keys
  debug:
    msg: "{{  item.instances[0].instance_type  }}   {{  item.instances[0].key_name  }}"
  loop: "{{ ec2_metadata.results }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the wrong syntax to expand a variable inside the expansion of the line.

```
debug: var= "{{ ec2_metadata.results[{{ item }}].instances[0].instance_id }}"
```

Correct

```
debug: var= "{{ ec2_metadata.results[item].instances[0].instance_id }}"
```

---

Quoting from the comment:

> debug: var= "{{ ec2_metadata.results[{{ item }}].instances[0].instance_id }}" this is working fine for me

A: The play below reproduces the error.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    list:
      - 'AAA'
      - 'BBB'
    item: 0
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list[item] }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list[{{ item }}] }}"
```

failes

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: {{ list[{{ item }}] }}"}

Comment: debug: var= "{{ ec2_metadata.results[{{ item }}].instances[0].instance_id }}" this is working fine for me, 
TASK [Record Users Access Keys] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "ec2_metadata.results[0].instances[0].instance_id": "i-03dbfd81f19297092"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "ec2_metadata.results[1].instances[0].instance_id": "i-0635aa1029bc74ba5"
}
my requirement here is to get this i-0635aa1029bc74ba5 and use it in other task ,please let me know , how i can do that